# Using static folding inside app folding Django

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-staticfiles, django-static

I have a static directory inside my apps folder. I added this line of code to my projects settings.py file

```
    STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
    '/var/www/static/',
]
```

The file continues to result in a 404 not found. I'm getting stuck, what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

It probably isn't mistake in your static files settings. But to be sure the relevant settings for `static` folder in app directories is `STATICFILES_FINDERS` https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#staticfiles-finders. But the `AppDirectoriesFinder` should be present by default so it is probably OK.

Your problem is probably in your URL scheme:

For development purposes make sure you have `django.contrib.staticfiles` in your installed apps, `DEBUG = True` and `STATIC_URL = '/static/'` (or something similar). Then you should be able access the files.

For deploying it is more complicated but essentially you have setup `STATIC_ROOT`, before starting the server run `python manage.py collectstatic` command which will copy all static files to one location and then setup your server (Nginx) to serve the files from this folder under `/static/` URL. Here is the official documentation https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/static-files/#deployment

*Note:* if your app is `foo` and you have `bar` file in your `static` directory under `foo` app the URL for the file will be `/static/foo/bar`.

Comment: I think I missled you. The static file isnt inside a specific app's folder. It is inside the folder with the other apps. It is possible or should I leave my css files in one app and just reference the css from that app's static files?

Comment: Oh then make sure you add `os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "apps", "static")` instead if it is in your apps folder (assuming `BASE_DIR` points at the root of the project).

Comment: This feels like the right answer, but it doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: Did you setup and check everything as I wrote in the main answer? It is still relevant :)

Comment: lets go down the list: django.contrib.staticfiles is installed, STATIC_URL is /static/, I don't know what STATICFILES_FINDERS is though.